# Restrict access to GO webservice to clients from local subnets

Tags: http, go

I'm writing a small web service in GO using just the GO http package. I want to restrict access to the web service to clients on the local subnets (127.0.0.1, 10.0.0.0/8, 172.16.0.0/12, 192.168.0.0/16).

I tried using a subnet mask as addr argument to [ListenAndServe](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ListenAndServe) but it exits with a "no such host" error.

EDIT:

This is the solution I came up with the help of @RickA and @Dewy Broto.

```
func JustLocal(handler http.Handler) http.Handler {
    var local_subnets []*net.IPNet
    local_subnet_s := []string{"127.0.0.1/31", "10.0.0.0/8", "172.16.0.0/12", "192.168.0.0/16"}

    for _,net_s := range local_subnet_s {
        _, n, _ := net.ParseCIDR(net_s)
        local_subnets = append(local_subnets, n)
    }

    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        fmt.Println(r.RemoteAddr)
        remote_ip := net.ParseIP(strings.Split(r.RemoteAddr, ":")[0])
        fmt.Println(remote_ip)

        local := false
        for _, local_subnet := range local_subnets {
            fmt.Println(local_subnet, remote_ip)
            if local_subnet.Contains(remote_ip) {
                local = true
                break
            }
        }
        if !local {
            http.Error(w, "go away", 403)
            return
        }
        handler.ServeHTTP(w, r)
        return
    })
}
```

It's a bit raw around the edges but it works as far as I could tell. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a handler that checks to see if the client's IP address is allowed before delegating to another handler:

```
type authorizationHandler struct {
    nets []*net.IPNet
    h handler
}

func (ah *authorizationHandler) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    ok := false
    ip := net.ParseIP(r.RemoteAddr)
    for _, n := range ah.nets {
       if n.Contains(ip) {
         ok := true
         break
       }
    }
    if !ok {
       http.Error(w, "go away", 403)
       return
    }
    ah.h(w, r)
}
```

Use this handler to wrap your the root handler:

```
err := ListenAndServe(addr, 
          &authorizationHandler{nets: allowedNets, h:rootHandler))
```

Note: I typed in the above code without compiling or testing it. Some tweaks are probably required around parsing and testing the remote address.

Comment: Accepted the answer as a custom handler looks like the most idiomatic solution to this problem.

Comment: r.RemoteAddr could include the port which will invalidate the string passed to ParseIP. So you might get `nil`

Answer (score 3):

The address in `ListenAndServe` is the address your server binds to *on the machine where it is running*. It is not some sort of ip whitelist thingy. This allows you to specify on what (network)interface you want to bind the server.

So if this machine has a ethernet card (`ifconfig`) that has the ipadress `10.0.100.100` you can bind `ListenAndServe` to `10.0.100.100:8123`.
The ip-less version `:8123` binds the server to all available interfaces. eg. `[::]:8123` (`netstat -l`), and is thus reachable from outside.

To get what you want you have a couple of options:

- Put the machine in a private subnet that you trust and bind `ListenAndServe` to
  the ip of that subnet on your machine. Thus it should only be routable from within that subnet.
- Use a webserver in front of this server, have it pass requests to it
  based on its ip acl (ex. [nginx](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-nginx-access-control-howto/))
- Implement your own ip(range) filtering in the go server code (eg. use `request.URL` and test that against your whitelist)

Comment: Gave an upvote for the general explanation and the different possibilites to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can listen on multiple ports / hosts, you have to call `ListenAndServe` multiple times.

```
func main() {
    addrs := []string{"127.0.0.1:8080", "10.0.0.1:8080", "172.16.0.1:8080", "192.168.0.1:8080", "192.168.1.1:8080"}
    errs := make(chan error)
    for _, addr := range addrs {
        go func(addr string) {
            errs <- http.ListenAndServe(addr, nil) //or replace the nil with your mux
        }(addr)
    }
    i := len(addrs)
    for err := range errs {
        fmt.Println(err)
        if i = i - 1; i == 0 {
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Or you could use nging and just make your go server listen on `127.0.0.1`.